# How to load symbol files to BCC profiler

Tags: bpf, ebpf, bcc-bpf

With bcc tools' profile, I am getting mostly "[unknown]" in the profile output on my C program. This is, of course, expected because the program symbol are not loaded. However, I am not sure how to properly load the symbols so that "profile" program can pick it up. I have built my program with debug enabled "-g", but how do I load the debug symbols to "profile"?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the DEBUGGING section in bcc profile's manpage:

> See "[unknown]" frames with bogus addresses? This can happen for different
> reasons. Your best approach is to get Linux perf to work first, and then to
> try this tool. Eg, "perf record -F 49 -a -g -- sleep 1; perf script", and
> to check for unknown frames there.
>
> The most common reason for "[unknown]" frames is that the target software has
> not been compiled
> with frame pointers, and so we can't use that simple method for walking the
> stack. The fix in that case is to use software that does have frame pointers,
> eg, gcc -fno-omit-frame-pointer, or Java's -XX:+PreserveFramePointer.
>
> Another reason for "[unknown]" frames is JIT compilers, which don't use a
> traditional symbol table. The fix in that case is to populate a
> /tmp/perf-PID.map file with the symbols, which this tool should read. How you
> do this depends on the runtime (Java, Node.js).
>
> If you seem to have unrelated samples in the output, check for other
> sampling or tracing tools that may be running. The current version of this
> tool can include their events if profiling happened concurrently. Those
> samples may be filtered in a future version.

In your case, since it's a C program, I would recommend compiling with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`.